# How to Handle SQL Exception Must Pass Parameter number 'x'?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to store Binary Data by using store procedure. Store procedure has three parameters. Last parameter will be containing Binary Data. But when I run a code it gives SQL Exception

> Must pass parameter number 3 and subsequent parameters as '@name =
>   value'. After the form '@name = value' has been used, all subsequent
>   parameters must be passed in the form '@name = value'.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC myProc @param1 = 8, @param2= '5.png', @FileSignature");
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnString))
 {
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    if (FileSignature == null) //FileSignature  is byte[]
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileSignature", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
        cmd.Parameters["@FileSignature"].Value = System.DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSignature", FileSignature); //FileSignature is byte[]
        int iReturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

Comment: Use the same method for passing all parameters.   Don't put the first two as a pair in the SQL Command text, and then add the third to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `@param=val` for some parameters and `@param` for others.
Also, this is not the proper way to execute a stored procedure using `sqlCommand`.
Please try reading the exception message. It's plain english and is there to help.
Try this:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnString),
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("myProc", conn) 
{
    cmd.CommandType = SqlCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 8);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", '5.png');

    if (FileSignature == null) //FileSignature  is byte[]
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileSignature", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);
        cmd.Parameters["@FileSignature"].Value = System.DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileSignature", FileSignature); //FileSignature is byte[]
    }
    conn.Open();
    int iReturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you supplied the first two parameters by name you must do so for all three.  So you need to update you SqlCommand text to include it `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC myProc @param1 = 8, @param2= '5.png', **@Parameter3** = @FileSignature");`

Replace @Parameter3 with the name from your Stored Proc or optional you could just not pass any names (as long as the parameters are in the same order in your procedure.

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC myProc 8, '5.png', @FileSignature");`